# GWT 2.7 Compilation Failed with existing project 2.6.1

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Hi I have updated my Eclipse Kepler to Oxygen, and GWT 2.6.1 to GWT 2.7 and java 7 to java 8 using this [link.](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/)

Now I am compiling my project then my project getting compilation failed i compiled with log as debug then i am getting Message

```
 Finding entry point classes
      Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.slicktechnologies.client.Slick_Erp'
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/slicktechnologies/client/Slick_Erp.java'
            [ERROR] com.slicktechnologies.client.reusabledata.ConditionDialogBox cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/slicktechnologies/client/reusabledata/ConditionDialogBox.java'
            [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/slicktechnologies/client/services/LogoutServiceAsync.java'
            [ERROR] com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.helperlayer.User cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/usr/local/google/home/dankurka/gwt/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/AbsolutePanel.java'
            [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/slicktechnologies/shared/common/helperlayer/User.java'
            [ERROR] com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.role.UserRole cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ComplexPanel.java'
            [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.Command cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/slicktechnologies/shared/common/role/UserRole.java'
            [ERROR] com.slicktechnologies.client.utility.Screen cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/slicktechnologies/client/utility/Screen.java'
            [ERROR] com.simplesoftwares.client.library.appskeleton.AppMemory cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/simplesoftwares/client/library/appskeleton/AppMemory.java'
            [ERROR] com.simplesoftwares.client.library.appstructure.ViewContainer cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/simplesoftwares/client/library/appstructure/ViewContainer.java'
            [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/simplesoftwares/client/library/appskeleton/AppSkeleton.java'
            [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/simplesoftwares/client/library/appskeleton/AppContainer.java'
            [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DockLayoutPanel cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/usr/local/google/home/dankurka/gwt/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.java'
            [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/simplesoftwares/client/library/libservice/LoginServiceAsync.java'
            [ERROR] com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.helperlayer.User cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/slicktechnologies/client/userprofile/changepassword/ChangePasswordPopupForm.java'
            [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/RND%2013%20aug%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/slicktechnologies/client/userprofile/UserLoginInfoPopupForm.java'
            [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/usr/local/google/home/dankurka/gwt/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.java'
            [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel cannot be resolved to a type
         Checked 17 dependencies for errors.
Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
```

Any help

Comment: In addition to Thomas's answer, keep in mind that migrating to Java8 without using a GWT compiler that supports it will cause problems - GWT 2.8 supports Java8, but 2.7 does _not_.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, this happens when GWT 2.7 tried to use a persistent unit cache from GWT 2.6. You need to clean/remove the persistent unit cache from GWT 2.6. Look for a ".gwt-unitCache" folder (or something like that) next to your "war" dir.